# I want to pass one function's return value as another funtion's argument in python

Tags: function, python-3.x

This is my code:

```
def fun_one(x):
    total = x + 5
    return total


def fun_two(y):
    y += 5
    return y

fun_one(5)
print(fun_two(fun_one()))
```

Now here I want to pass `fun_one`'s return value as argument to `fun_two`. How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it as:

```
def fun_one(x):
    total = x + 5
    return total


def fun_two(y):
    y += 5
    return y

print(fun_two(fun_one(5)))
```

Or you can also do it as:

```
def fun_one(x):
    total = x + 5
    return total


def fun_two(y):
    y += 5
    return y

temp=fun_one(5)
print(fun_two(temp))
```

Answer (score 0):

Call your `fun_one(5)` inside `fun_two()` like so:

```
# Replace these lines
fun_one(5)
print(fun_two(fun_one()))

# With this
print(fun_two(fun_one(5)))
```